# How to Play Videos PHAsset in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, video, nsurl, phasset

I want to play video from `PHAsset`, collected from iOS Photos. `PHAsset` video `nsurl` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35099857/1084174) is valid to my own application lets say `MyPlayer` for few moments/blocks. When I am copying the image/video into `MyPlayers` own sandbox only then the `nsurl` becomes always valid. It seems to me,

> I need to copy each video from temporary `PHAsset` nsurl to MyPlayers
>   sandbox (appgroup/documents) and only then I can play the video with
>   sandbox relative nsurl.

If this is the case how do all other player play long videos on the fly? If there is any other way to play video without copying to apps sandbox, please let me know the way.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

After several days experiment finally I come upon a solution,

#### Import File

```
import AVKit
```

#### From PHAsset

```
static func playVideo (view:UIViewController, asset:PHAsset) {

        guard (asset.mediaType == PHAssetMediaType.Video)

            else {
                print("Not a valid video media type")
                return
        }

        PHCachingImageManager().requestAVAssetForVideo(asset, options: nil, resultHandler: {(asset: AVAsset?, audioMix: AVAudioMix?, info: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) in

            let asset = asset as! AVURLAsset

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                let player = AVPlayer(URL: asset.URL)
                let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
                playerViewController.player = player
                view.presentViewController(playerViewController, animated: true) {
                    playerViewController.player!.play()
                }
            })
        })
    }
```

#### From AppLocalUrl

```
static func playVideo (view:UIViewController, appLocalUrl:NSURL) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

            let player = AVPlayer(URL: appLocalUrl)
            let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
            playerViewController.player = player
            view.presentViewController(playerViewController, animated: true) {
                playerViewController.player!.play()
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: I have tested this piece of code and it does not work for slow-motion videos. So I have modified this solution.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60292456/397915

Answer (score 7):

@Sazzad Hissain Khan solution in Swift 3:

**From PHAsset:**

```
func playVideo (view: UIViewController, videoAsset: PHAsset) {

    guard (videoAsset.mediaType == .video) else {
        print("Not a valid video media type")
        return
    }

    PHCachingImageManager().requestAVAsset(forVideo: videoAsset, options: nil) { (asset, audioMix, args) in
        let asset = asset as! AVURLAsset

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let player = AVPlayer(url: asset.url)
            let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
            playerViewController.player = player
            view.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
                playerViewController.player!.play()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**From AppLocalUrl:**

```
func playVideo (view: UIViewController, appLocalUrl: URL) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        let player = AVPlayer(url: appLocalUrl)
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerViewController.player = player
        view.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
            playerViewController.player!.play()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gotta look out for `AVComposition` assets.  They're things like slow motion video.  If you run into one of those, create an `AVPlayerItem` with it and pass the player item into the `AVPlayer`.

Answer (score 5):

**The below solution works for slow-motion videos as well.**

```
func playVideo(asset: PHAsset) {
    guard asset.mediaType == .video else {
        // Handle if the asset is not a video.
        return
    }

    let options = PHVideoRequestOptions()
    options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true

    PHCachingImageManager().requestPlayerItem(forVideo: asset, options: options) { (playerItem, info) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
            playerViewController.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
            present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
                playerViewController.player?.play()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 5

```
func playVideo(view:UIViewController, asset:PHAsset) {

        guard (asset.mediaType == PHAssetMediaType.video)

            else {
                print("Not a valid video media type")
                return
        }

        PHCachingImageManager().requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset, options: nil) { (assets, audioMix, info) in
            let asset = assets as! AVURLAsset
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                let player = AVPlayer(url: asset.url)
                let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
                playerViewController.player = player
                view.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
                    playerViewController.player!.play()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: your solution is not working on some devices with crash on this " let asset = assets as! AVURLAsset " with message: "Could not cast value of type 'AVComposition' (0x1ed8ebd88) to 'AVURLAsset' (0x1ed8eb680)" Can you guide me about this error?

Comment: I also tried with this but same error
PHImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: phAsset, options: nil, resultHandler: {(asset: AVAsset?, audioMix: AVAudioMix?, info: [AnyHashable : Any]?) -> Void in