# SVGKit: How do i render an SVG XML String that references a iOS device photo using SVGKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, svg, svgkit, phassetslibrary

### So, my basic question is:

Is there a way on iOS to use SVGKit to render SVG that contains references to local images?

### Gory Details

My application needs to generate and render SVG (XML in an NSString). The XML will reference image URLs on the device (in the Camera Roll). I'm using [SVGKit](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit) for iOS. I am able to get URLs from image PHAssets using the following (see: [StackOverflow:nsurl-from-phasset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26025487/nsurl-from-phasset) ):

```objc
+ (void) getUrlFromPHAsset:(PHAsset *)asset 
         completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURL *url)) handler {

    PHImageRequestOptions *imgOptions = [PHImageRequestOptions new];
    PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions *options = 
                              [PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions new];
    imgOptions.version = PHImageRequestOptionsVersionCurrent;

    [asset requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:options 
            completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput * _Nullable contentEditingInput, NSDictionary * _Nonnull info) {
        handler(contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL);
    }];
}
```

I then use that image URL in my generated SVG XML string (this one was generated in the simulator):

```xml
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="2175px" height="1537px" viewBox="0 0 2175 1537" style="background-color:#ffffff">

<defs>
    <clipPath id="my-uuid" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse">  <rect x="1062" y="-1" width="1111" height="1538"/>
    </clipPath>
</defs>

<g clip-path="url(#my-uuid)">
    <image overflow="hidden" transform="translate(1062, -64.58393285371704) rotate(0, 555, 832)" x="0" y="0" width="1111" height="1665.167865707434" xlink:href="file:///Users/joe/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E8B8D888-93EC-4152-B0AD-B82D0C1B2FFE/data/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0003.JPG"></image>
</g>
</svg>
```

### What I've tried

I attempted to use **SVGKSourceString** to create an **SVGKImage**, but this returns a blank image for the local image URL (remote URL references work fine). By "blank image", I mean a non-nil object with a size, but no image content.

```objc
// DOESNT WORK on Simulator or real device
+ (SVGKImage *) svgImageFromString:(NSString *)text {
    SVGKSource *source = [SVGKSourceString sourceFromContentsOfString:svgText];
    SVGKImage *img = [SVGKImage imageWithSource:source]; // returns a blank image
}
```

I noticed on the simulator that if I read the SVG content from a file on the device, it worked. I thought that was weird, but, whatever. When it reads the SVG content from a file, it must handle URL references differently. So, I turned the NSString into an NSInputStream, then used SVGSourceLocalFile.initWithInputStream: to create the SVGKSourceLocalFile, and it too worked on the simulator. The local image referenced in the SVG rendered. (NOTE: I had to set filePath with a phoney file name to prevent imageWithSource from blowing up.)

But, sadly, this didn't work on a real device. SVGKImage imageSource: comes back with a blank image.

```objc
// WORKS ON THE SIMULATOR, not on a real device
+ (SVGKImage *) svgImageFromString:(NSString *)text {
    NSData *svgData = [text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSInputStream *inp = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithData:svgData];
    SVGKSourceLocalFile *fsource = [[SVGKSourceLocalFile alloc] initWithInputSteam:inp];
    // hack: set filePath to prevent SVGKit from barfing
    fsource.filePath = @"foo.bar";
    return [SVGKImage imageWithSource:fsource];
}
```

I strongly suspect that it didn't like the device URL reference. I know there are issues getting a generic URL from a PHAsset. The URL on the simulator works in Safari simulator. But the URL I get back on the real device (looks like "file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/102APPLE/IMG_2405.JPG") did NOT work on the device's Safari app. I also tried converting the PHAsset to an ALAssetURL.. (see [StackOverflow:how-to-get-an-alasset-url-from-a-phasset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28887638/how-to-get-an-alasset-url-from-a-phasset) ), but that too, did not work. That also returns a blank image.

### Version Details

- iOS version: 10.0.2 (real device), various version on sim (8.4, 9.3, 10.0)
- SVGKit version: pod 'SVGKit', :git => 'https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit.git', :branch => '2.x'

Answer (score 0):

SVGKit uses Apple's own classes to parse those URL's, and does *no* additional processing on them.

So ... if you're getting a nil image, you're *probably* breaking NSURL's own parsing capabilities - c.f. Apple's docs.

However ... if you run the Xcode debugger, set a breakpoint on the SVGKit SVGKSourceXXXXX class you're using, and run on device, you should be able to easily see in realtime what's failing and where - my guess is NSURL, but you could confirm this.